# Submitting Multiple Forms with one Javascript function works in FF and no other browser

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

Here is the code I borrowed from other posts, but it only works in FF and not in Chrome, Opera, Safari, nor IE:

```
//Collect all forms in document to one and post it 

function submitAllDocumentForms() {

    var arrDocForms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    var formCollector = document.createElement("form");

    with(formCollector){
        method = "post";
        action = "saveSession.php";
        name = "formCollector";
        id = "formCollector";
    }
    for(var ix=0;ix<arrDocForms.length;ix++) {
        appendFormVals2Form(arrDocForms[ix], formCollector);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(formCollector);
    formCollector.submit();

}

// Function: add all elements from ``frmCollectFrom´´ 
// and append them to ``frmCollector´´ before returning ``frmCollector´´

function appendFormVals2Form(frmCollectFrom, frmCollector) {

    var frm = frmCollectFrom.elements; 
    var nElems = frm.length;
    for(var ix = nElems - 1; ix >= 0 ; ix--)
        frmCollector.appendChild(frm[ix]);
        return frmCollector;
}
```

I think must have multiple forms on the same page for summing up input values to the correct field. It would be a major rework even if possible.

Comment: Using `with` is a bad idea. Does IE have an error message? What does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect this to work on all browsers. Once a form is submitted the browser's "browse context" (for want of a better word) is then committed to seeing that new request go through unless or until the user cancels it by pressing the browser Stop button.

So once a form has been submitted it won't (or rather: shouldn't be) be possible to submit any other form. The fact that you can with FF/Gecko just means that they've implemented their browser such that it is possible, but no part of various web standards stipulates that this must be possible.

Reworded: Submitting a form puts the Javascript execution context into a new state where, presumably and except in Firefox's case, new form submission is impossible because another one is currently underway.

Your best bet for a solution is to use AJAX (or just XmlHttpRequest) for firing off various POST requests asynchronously. It isn't that big a task to use it - but I suspect you're probably doing everything entirely wrong. Why do you need to perform this task in the first place?

Comment: "but I suspect you're probably doing everything entirely wrong. Why do you need to perform this task in the first place?"  Wow, thanks for that comment!